# error CS0019: Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to my code to cater for Small letter and Capital letter string values. when I use || operator in Visual studio 2022 I get this error "CS0019: Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'" but when I change to "or" it works on visual studio 2022 but when I compile the code outside of visual studio I get the same error "CS0019: Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'". Is there another way can user or operator that will make on any environment. C# console application

see code below:

`switch (value) { case "A" or "a": cardValue = 11; break; case "J" or "j": cardValue = 11; break; case "Q" or "q": cardValue = 12; break; case "K" or "k": cardValue = 13; break; }`

I tried using

`case "A" or "a": cardValue = 11; break;`

and
`case "A" || "a": cardValue = 11; break;`

Comment: `or` was a keyword added to C# 9 - for older version of C# you should use multiple case statements for one block as described in the answer to the  marked duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this: add each option as below example A and a are added.

```
switch(value)
{
    case a:
    case A:
    ...do something....
    break;
}
```